# How to exclude CustomResourceDefinition from rendering in Helm?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I'm currently writing a Helm Chart for my multi-service application. In the application, I depend on `CustomResources`, which I apply before everything else with helm via the `"helm.sh/hook": crd-install` hook.

Now I want to upgrade the application. Helm fails because the CRDs are already installed.
In some GH issues, I read about the builtin `.Capabilities` variable in Helm templates. I want to wrap my CRDs with an "if" checking if the CRD is already installed:

```
{{- if (not (.Capabilities.APIVersions.Has "virtualmachineinstancepresets.kubevirt.io")) }}
```

Unfortunately, I misunderstood the APIVersions property.
So my question is, does Helm provide a way of checking whether a `CustomAPI` is already installed, so I can exclude it from my Helm pre-hook install?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple answer for Helm v2 is manually choose `--no-crd-hook` flag when running `helm install`.

The workaround by using builtin `.Capabilities` variable can be a workaround. E.g., using this:

```
{{- if not (.Capabilities.APIVersions.Has "virtualmachineinstancepresets.kubevirt.io/v1beta1/MyResource") }}
apiVersion: ...
{{- end}}
```

However, it also means you will never be able to manage the installed CRDs by Helm again.

Checkout a long answer from blog post [Helm V2 CRD Management](https://joejulian.name/post/helm-v2-crd-management/) which explained different approaches. However, I quote this:

> CRD management in helm is, to be nice about it, utterly horrible.

personally I suggest managing CRDs via a separate chart out of app/library charts that depends on it, since they have totally different lifecycle.